# Desabilitar scroll do mouse

Tags: html, css

Meu código.

***Css:***

```
td div{
 width:100%; 
 height: 40px; 
 overflow: hidden; 
 padding-top: 9px;
}
 td div:hover{
  overflow: auto;
}
```

***Html:***

```
<td><div><?php echo $objProg->getagen(); ?></div></td>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao por o mouse encima da `td` gostaria que a opção para rolar com o scroll do mouse não funcionasse, para conseguir somente rolar o texto ao clicar nas setas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma muito facil de fazer, sem precisar de muitas linhas e muito simples:

use: `onwheel="return false;"`

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rapa09/jtxf10qm/1/

Comment: Só pra constar, se interessar tem o "Fiddle" do próprio site, que é o ícone da folha com < > na barra de ferramentas da resposta (mas é perfeitamente normal usar o JS Fiddle também)

Comment: Eu utilizei o do site, mas se eu clicar fora sem querer ele não salva os codigos, então prefiro usar o jsfiddle. mas vlw pela dica.

Comment: Única coisa que eu não achei muito interessante é que quando o mouse esta encima da `div` o scroll da página em si não rola também.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando jQuery você pode fazer isso de algumas formas. Pode simplesmente desabilitar o `scroll` como deseja, ou forçar o `scroll` a funcionar somente na `div` em questão.

Ficaria assim os exemplos:

```js
$('#good').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    var scrollTo = null;

    if (e.type == 'mousewheel') {
        scrollTo = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta * -1);
    }
    else if (e.type == 'DOMMouseScroll') {
        scrollTo = 40 * e.originalEvent.detail;
    }

    if (scrollTo) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).scrollTop(scrollTo + $(this).scrollTop());
    }
});

$('#bad').hover(function() {
    $(document).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',function(){ 
        stopWheel(); 
    });
}, function() {
    $(document).unbind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll');
});


function stopWheel(e){
    if(!e){ /* IE7, IE8, Chrome, Safari */ 
        e = window.event; 
    }
    if(e.preventDefault) { /* Chrome, Safari, Firefox */ 
        e.preventDefault(); 
    } 
    e.returnValue = false; /* IE7, IE8 */
}
```

```css
body { min-height: 1200px; padding: 30px; }
p { height: 500px; }
div#bad {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 330px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    overflow: scroll; 
}

div#good {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 30px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: gray;
    overflow: scroll; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Scroll to bottom of each div</div>
<div id="good">
    <p>Scroll somente na div</p>
    End of Div
</div>
<div id="bad">
    <p>Remove Scroll jQuery</p>
    End of Div
</div>
```

Demais formas, você pode olhar [nesta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7571370/4843158) que usei como referência.